# 60's (or earlier) movie with aliens pretending to browse magazines while talking telepathically

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

I saw a movie on TV around mid to late 60's that had one scene where two alien humanoids are standing at a magazine rack in a drug store or department store and pretending to browse while talking back and forth telepathically.

I can't remember if they took over humans bodies or if they just assumed human form. I do think it was a man and a woman but not sure.

Comment: Possibly the old BBC series, [*Sapphire and Steel?*](http://m.imdb.com/title/tt0078682/)

Comment: Thanks Joe, but I'm pretty sure it wasn't a series. I saw it while I was visiting relatives in Pekin, IL. (I can't ask them if they remember because they have long since passed away.) It was one those old weekly "Chiller Theater" or  "Thriller Theater" shows. I'm pretty sure they only showed movies.

Comment: "Not of This Earth"(1957)? It had a male and female alien communicating this way.